# How to count number of columns having a certain values using Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have an Employee Attendance table in the database, with these columns:

```
ID | Date | EmployeeId | Day1 | Day2 | Day3.... | Day31

1  | .... | ...........| 1    |  1   |  1 ..... | 5
```

Day1 to Day31 has integer values ranging from 1 to 5 with each having a specific meaning. suppose we have 1 under the columns from Day1 to Day28 and 5 under the columns Day29 to Day31, Here We have 28 1s and 3 5s against ID 1.

**ToDo**

I want to count against a specific ID, that how many of the columns have value 1, how many have value 2, how many have value 3, how many have value 4, how many have value 5. (using Entity Framework)

Sample code:

```
public class LeaveBalance
{
        public int ShortLeave { get; set; }
        public int HalfLeave { get; set; }
        public int FullLeaves { get; set; }
        public int Absent { get; set; }
        public Guid EmpCode { get; set; }
        public Employee Employee { get; set; }
        public int TotalLeaves { get; set; }              
}
```

I am having difficulty counting:

```
public List<LeaveBalance> ReturnCount(DateTime date)
{
    List<LeaveBalance> count = new List<LeaveBalance>();

    using (var _db = new AppDbContext())
    {
        var employee = _db.EmployeeAttendanceSheets
                          .Where(r => r.Date.Month == date.Date.Month && r.Date.Year == date.Date.Year)
                          .ToList();

        foreach (var emp in employee)
        {
            count.Add(new LeaveBalance { Absent = })
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Please help and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var item = context.Table.Find(id);
var data = item.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name.Contains("Day"))
               .Select(x => (int)x.GetValue(item)).ToList();
var answer = Enumerable.Range(1, 5)
             .Select(x => new { number = x, count = data.Count(y => y == x) }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank You very much it is working like a charm and you saved my day